# Spring MVC jsp not found when path contains multiple parts

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, kotlin

Any help is appreciated. I have Spring Boot MVC application and have noticed some inconsistencies with my view being rendered. I am currently using Spring Boot starter parent with version 2.3.4.RELEASE, Spring Security and an embedded Tomcat Server and Kotlin (in eclipse. yes i agree that was probably a mistake because kotlin support in ecliplse is very lacking)

When mapping a Get Request with just a single /findData my application finds and renders the view correctly. Using a multipart /moreSpecific/findData url the application returns with a 404 not found for the jsp. I am not sure what the difference is but the application cannot find my jsp's based upon the requestMapping?

It is not failing with a 403 so I do not believe that it is a Spring Security issue

```
Application.properties
spring.mvc.view.prefix=WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

RequestMappings / stack

```
@RequestMapping( value=["/findData"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
fun get(): String {
    return "findData"
}
```

2020-10-22 22:08:39.482 DEBUG 16376 --- [io-61558-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [WEB-INF/jsp/findData.jsp]
2020-10-22 22:08:39.485 DEBUG 16376 --- [io-61558-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 O

```
@RequestMapping( value=["/moreSpecific/findData"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
fun get(): String {
    return "findData"
}
```

2020-10-22 22:08:39.482 DEBUG 16376 --- [io-61558-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [WEB-INF/jsp/findData.jsp]
2020-10-22 22:08:39.485 DEBUG 16376 --- [io-61558-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

I am truly confounded by this. Is this a tomcat behavior?

Comment: how do you map jsp files ?

Comment: add `logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
logging.level.com=TRACE` to the properties file to have a detailed debug

Comment: please post the controller file